# Writing a class in a type-safe way

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to write a type-safe code. Here's what I've tried:

```
public interface ResultTronsformer<T>{
    public T tranform(T t);
}

public class BigDecimalTransformer implements ResultTRansformer<BigDecimal>{

    public BigDecimal transform(BigDecimal t){
        return t.setScale(0);
    }
}
```

Now I define the Column interface which looks like

```
public interface Column{
    public ResultTransformer<?> getTransformer();
}
```

and would like to use it in the method

```
public class Report{
    private Map<Column, Object> columnValuePairs;

    public void putIntoACollection(Column c, Object columnsValue){
         ResultTransformer<?> rt = c.getTransformer();
         columnValuePairs.put(c, rt.transform(o)); //Error: Couldn't convert Object 
                                                   //to the capture of wildcard
    }
}
```

How can I rearrange the design to reach the desirable type-safety? Maybe I should do the type-checking at runtime instead (throwing an exception)?

Comment: Java's type system is not strong enough to do this. But you can use some wrapper libraries which expose an **externally** safe API. For instance: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html

Comment: @Max Intersting, have not heard about that approach. Maybe you can provide an example as an asnwer?

Answer (score 2):

You can think about the Column just like it is some kind of container that holds specific type. In that way, you can introduce generic type in Column declaration.

```java
public interface Column<T>{
    public ResultTransformer<T> getTransformer();
}
```

Then, you can change Report method as follows:

```java
public <T> void putIntoACollection(Column<T> c, T columnsValue){
        ResultTransformer<T> rt = c.getTransformer();
        columnValuePairs.put(c, rt.transform(columnsValue)); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - that's a great first post! Spot on.

Comment: This does not solve the issue because you can only insert columns of one type. The meat of the problem is the the columns store different types.

Comment: I don't now the whole context of this reporting feature but I understand that Column is a container that contains some value. You can create any number of columns for each supported type. Value in the Column can be transformed by referenced ResultTransformer. This ResultTransformer, as a type safe component, should operate on the same type of data that column stores. If you will have any type hierarchy, single ResultTransformer can be extended to operate on multiple types on the same hierarchy level.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `Column` class and make it parametrized:

```
public interface Column<T> {
    public ResultTransformer<T> getTransformer();
}
```

Then you have to parametrize the `putIntoACollection` method (no need to parametrize `Report`):

```
public class Report {
    private Map<Column, Object> columnValuePairs;

    public <T> void putIntoACollection(Column<T> c, T columnsValue) {
        final ResultTransformer<T> rt = c.getTransformer();
        columnValuePairs.put(c, rt.transform(columnsValue));
    }
}
```

This way, you never need to use a capture type.

Here is an example of how you would use it:

```
private class BigDecimalColumn implements Column<BigDecimal> {
    @Override
    public ResultTransformer<BigDecimal> getTransformer() {
        return new BigDecimalTransformer();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Report report = new Report();
    report.putIntoACollection(new BigDecimalColumn(), new BigDecimal("3.14"));
}
```

Comment: But how do you think I can implement the Column interface then? For instance, I need `BigDecimalColumn` which in turn is a sublclass of `ResultTransformer<BigDecimal>`. We'll get a compiler unchecked warning.

Comment: @user3663882 this question will be impossible to solve in a way that doesn't produce that warning. The only thing to do will be to write provably type safe code and add a `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")`.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the transformer, you need to specify the type because the compiler won't know it at that time.

A possible solution is to add the class as a parameter to the getTransformer of the Column and return a specialized ResultTransformer.

```
public interface ResultTransformer<T> {
    public T transform(T t);
}

public interface Column{
    public <T> ResultTransformer<T> getTransformer(Class<T> theClass);
}

public class Report{
   private Map<Column, Object> columnValuePairs;

   public void putIntoACollection(Column c, Object o){
       ResultTransformer<Object> rt = c.getTransformer(Object.class);
       columnValuePairs.put(c, rt.transform(o));
   }

public interface ResultTransformer<T> {
    public T transform(T t);
}
```

Another way would be to generalize the interface Column.

Comment: Again, implementation of the Column interface will be unsafe. Or I don;t understand something....?

Comment: You could also generalize the Column interface to Column<T> but that would bind the Column 's type parameters to the result of the ResultTransformer which is not a dependency I would choose. In the future you might want to have multiple transformers for one Column and that will not be possible anymore. It depends on which class will carry the responsibility of defining the return type of the transformer. If it is the column, make Column<T>.  If it is the ResultTransformer then this is a good way.

Answer (score 0):

We could give up all pretenses, just use the god damned raw type

```
     ResultTransformer rt = c.getTransformer();
```

A more pretentious solution -

```
    static <T> T transform (ResultTransformer<T> rt, Object obj)
    {
        T t = (T)obj; // unchecked cast
        return rt.transform(t);
    }


public void putIntoACollection(Column c, Object obj){
     ResultTransformer<?> rt = c.getTransformer();
     columnValuePairs.put(c, transform(rt, obj) );

}
```